# Bottom bar got hidden when pushed from view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to show the bottom bar when pushed from another view controller ?

Viewcontroller.m

```
ReminderViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReminderViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The viewcontroller does not contain any tabbar but `ReminderViewController` contains tabbar. However, when it was pushed, it did not show the tab bar at the bottom. Am I pushing it wrongly ?

Comment: you need to set as tabbar as rootViewController instead of push .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your naming - *"ReminderViewController"* - it sounds like you are loading and pushing the *first view controller in your tab bar controller* instead of the tab bar controller itself.

You need to subclass your tab bar controller. It doesn't need any special code... can be as simple as this:

```
//  MyTabBarViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTabBarViewController : UITabBarController
@end
```

---

```
//  MyTabBarViewController.m
#import "MyTabBarViewController.h"

@interface MyTabBarViewController ()
@end

@implementation MyTabBarViewController
@end
```

---

Then, load and push your tab bar controller instead of the first tab's view:

```
    MyTabBarViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTabBarViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

---

[image]